# JSP Application Login

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I created a login with a JSP with a Servlet and a Bean.

First of all my current code:

JSP:

```
<body>    
<jsp:useBean id="login" class="login.LoginBean" scope="session"/>

<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="loginmodal-container">
        <h1>Login to use BIDeploy</h1><br>
        <form method="post" action="LoginServlet">
            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="submit" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

My bean "LoginBean" has just have Getter and Setter.

Servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
    LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
    request.setAttribute("loginBean", loginBean);

    loginBean.setUser(request.getParameter("user"));
    loginBean.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));

    request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

And my problem starts here: How can I use my username and password to login into SVN, Jira and more? I need to use the $-Tag

index.JSP

```
...
<jsp:useBean id="login" class="login.LoginBean" scope="session"/>

${svnHelper.setup("svn-link",login.username,login.password)}
...
```

Thanks :)

UPDATE:
Okay I just have an idea now but i dunno how to realize it: 
My problem is that I don't save the username and password in the session.

I tried this without success:

```
input type="password" name="password" value="${sessionScope.password}" placeholder="Password"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login servlet's **doPost()**, call:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("loggedInUser", loginBean);
```

And then you can access these attributes with EL, e.g.:

```
${sessionScope.loggedInUser.user)
```

Then, as @MrSimpleMind suggested, you have to find API-s to the SVN, etc., but as far as I understood, you had trouble accessing the variables.

Comment: Anytime, glad I could help. :)

Comment: i would vote up but i can't i need some more reputation :D

Comment: It's okay, and if you need any more help in servlets/JSP let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on some kind of authentication in your web app. Search for Basic or form-based Authentication. It is very simple and it will give you standard way for handling user credentials, involving JAAS.

Then you need to look for different login apis for the different vendors. For example check the [Jira REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis). And check the [SVN SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/index.html) which will give you integration possibilities from your web app.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I already have a filter authentication with a backend. But this backend doesn't supply the username and password --> also i need a second authentication to save the username and password for this session to connect to jira and svn

I am already using SVNKit and the Jira API